# Meteor absolute URL

Tags: mongodb, meteor

For absolute URL my code is as following:

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl() + 'listing/' + listing._id
```

but when I try with the same using the same template on my homepage I am getting undefined.

what can I do abt it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Meteor Absolute URL Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl) describes usage and path after the ROOT_URL is the first parameter to the Meteor.absoluteUrl method.

I think you method call should be
`Meteor.absoluteUrl('listing/' + listing._id)`